# Closing duplicate tabs in macOS Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I have nearly 300 tabs open and going through them by hand is going to take forever. I know I can sort them to make it a bit easier but it's still going to be very time consuming and doesn't really work if the tab title changes because of a notification for example. Is there any quicker way of getting rid of duplicates?

Comment: sort them by website, then you will see the group

Comment: @Ruskes that doesn't really help - I already have them sorted by website. I mentioned sorting in my question too, I'm looking for a different method

Answer (score 0):

Apple implemented a feature to help you not get into the situation, but it won’t help for cleaning up.

- https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/ibrwecff96b7/mac

If I were going to script this cleanup myself, here is the best script I know to start from.

- https://daringfireball.net/linked/2023/12/05/an-applescript-for-safari-split-tabs-to-new-window

If you’re new to AppleScript - get the amazing tool Script Debugger - there’s a paid and lite version to consider.

- https://latenightsw.com/sd8/feature-comparison/

Or this app seems to be updated often by a respectable developer and is very inexpensive if you can’t spend hours learning how to DIY.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tabs-saver-for-safari/id1440006971?mt=12

Comment: If you’re making the website, you have options to warn people doing this, but it’s not likely this will help us that want [all sites to work this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231610/475228).